# sed command replaces all lines containing "name"

Tags: sed

I have a document with the next data:

```
SOMETHING_NAME=something
NAME=somethingmore
```

And when I run the next command:

```
sed -i "/NAME=/c NAME=newsomething" ./file
```

The command edit all matching with NAME, so I need to match only the second line.

file after:

```
NAME=newsomething
NAME=newsomething
```

The output I need:

```
SOMETHING_NAME=something
NAME=newsomething
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a caret (^) to the regex that will match from the start of the line, as follow.

```
sed -i "/^NAME=/c NAME=newsomething" ./file
```

Comment: PS: `NAME=` part is repeated twice in this solution.

Comment: this is intentional.  the first NAME= is whats called the address, and it is optional and often not needed.  but it is the ability to limit which lines the sed command is called on.

Comment: Imagine a regex pattern instead of plain text `NAME=`. Best is to [match, capture and reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627819/548225).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this simple `sed` command using a capture group and start anchor:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E 's/^(NAME=).*/\1newsomething/' file

cat file

SOMETHING_NAME=something
NAME=newsomething
```

**Breakup:**

- `^` Start a line
- `(NAME=)`: Match substring `NAME=` and capture in group #1
- `.*`: Match rest of the line
- `\1newsomething`: Replacement is `\1` (back-reference of group #1) followed by `newsomething`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine sed with `\b` to define word bountaries.
I think bellow examples will help you better to understand the use of it and how you can use it in your case:

```
cat file1
name1 name2 name3
_name1 _name2 _name3

sed 's/\b_name1\b/XX/' file1
name1 name2 name3
XX _name2 _name3

sed 's/\bname1\b/XX/' file1
XX name2 name3
_name1 _name2 _name3

sed 's/\bname\b/XX/' file1
name1 name2 name3
_name1 _name2 _name3
# nothing is replaced since name is not a word/field in file1
```